# EXE or DLL Image base address

Tags: c++, windows, portable-executable, base-address

Is there a way in C++/windows to get the exe/DLL image base address?
thanks :)

Comment: You can use (in addition to the other answers) EnumProcessModulesEx  and GetModuleInformation which allows you to find this information out for other processes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you load the binary into your own process you can use [GetModuleHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683199(VS.85).aspx). It returns a HMODULE, but that is [the same as HINSTANCE and the base address](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040614-00/?p=38903).

If you want to know what base address the binary prefers you should read the PE header. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx) and look for the ImageBase field in IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER.

Edit: GetModuleHandle(NULL) will return the base address (altough the specified type is HMODULE) for the current process.

Answer (score 7):

If you are examining an DLL or EXE file on disk, use the [dumpbin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/756as972.aspx) utility.  It in installed with Visual Studio or the SDK.

Example Output of [dumpbin /headers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429):

```
FILE HEADER VALUES
     14C machine (i386)
       6 number of sections
306F7A22 time date stamp Sun Oct 01 22:35:30 1995
       0 file pointer to symbol table
     1D1 number of symbols
      E0 size of optional header
     302 characteristics
            Executable
            32 bit word machine
            Debug information stripped

OPTIONAL HEADER VALUES
     10B magic #
    2.60 linker version
    1E00 size of code
    1E00 size of initialized data
       0 size of uninitialized data
    1144 address of entry point
    1000 base of code
    3000 base of data
         ----- new -----
 **2BB0000 image base**  <--- This is what you are looking for
    1000 section alignment
     200 file alignment
       3 subsystem (Windows CUI)
    4.00 operating system version
    4.00 image version
    3.50 subsystem version
    8000 size of image
     400 size of headers
    62C8 checksum
  100000 size of stack reserve
    1000 size of stack commit
  100000 size of heap reserve
    1000 size of heap commit
       0 [       0] address [size] of Export Directory
    5000 [      3C] address [size] of Import Directory
    6000 [     394] address [size] of Resource Directory
       0 [       0] address [size] of Exception Directory
       0 [       0] address [size] of Security Directory
    7000 [     21C] address [size] of Base Relocation Directory
    3030 [      38] address [size] of Debug Directory
       0 [       0] address [size] of Description Directory
       0 [       0] address [size] of Special Directory
       0 [       0] address [size] of Thread Storage Directory
       0 [       0] address [size] of Load Configuration Directory
     268 [      44] address [size] of Bound Import Directory
    50A0 [      64] address [size] of Import Address Table Directory
       0 [       0] address [size] of Reserved Directory
       0 [       0] address [size] of Reserved Directory
       0 [       0] address [size] of Reserved Directory

SECTION HEADER #1
   .text name
    1D24 virtual size
    1000 virtual address
    1E00 size of raw data
     400 file pointer to raw data
       0 file pointer to relocation table
    3C20 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
     37E number of line numbers
60000020 flags
         Code
         (no align specified)
         Execute Read
```

Answer (score 7):

I found that the most convenient and accurate way to get module's base address (and in-memory image size) is through GetModuleInformation (include psapi.h, link to psapi.lib):

```
MODULEINFO module_info; memset(&module_info, 0, sizeof(module_info));
if (GetModuleInformation(GetCurrentProcess(), hModule, &module_info, sizeof(module_info))) {
    DWORD module_size = module_info.SizeOfImage;
    BYTE * module_ptr = (BYTE*)module_info.lpBaseOfDll;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get your own ImageBase Address from inside a DLL/EXE then how about this:

```
#include <winnt.h>

EXTERN_C IMAGE_DOS_HEADER __ImageBase;
```

Comment: and in the debugger; can add a watch on &__ImageBase

Answer (score 2):

If you want to enumerate all process's modules, you can also use [CreateToolhelp32Snapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h> 

std::vector<std::pair<std::string, uint32_t> > base_addresses;
// take a snapshot of all modules in the specified process
HANDLE snaphot_handle = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, 0);
if (snaphot_handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    // first module
    MODULEENTRY32 mod_entry;
    mod_entry.dwSize = sizeof(mod_entry);
    if (Module32First(snaphot_handle, &mod_entry))
    {
        // iterate through the module list of the process
        do
        {
            base_addresses.push_back(
                    std::make_pair(mod_entry.szModule,
                                   static_cast<uint32_t>(mod_entry.modBaseAddr));
        } while (Module32Next(snaphot_handle, &mod_entry));
    }

    CloseHandle(snaphot_handle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find below code to find Image Base Address in CPP :

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    LPCSTR fileName="inputFile.exe";
    HANDLE hFile;
    HANDLE hFileMapping;
    LPVOID lpFileBase;
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS peHeader;
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER sectionHeader;

    hFile = CreateFileA(fileName,GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0);

    if(hFile==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::cout<<"\n CreateFile failed \n";
        return 1;
    }

    hFileMapping = CreateFileMapping(hFile,NULL,PAGE_READONLY,0,0,NULL);

    if(hFileMapping==0)
    {
        std::cout<<"\n CreateFileMapping failed \n";
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return 1;
    }

    lpFileBase = MapViewOfFile(hFileMapping,FILE_MAP_READ,0,0,0);

    if(lpFileBase==0)
    {
        std::cout<<"\n MapViewOfFile failed \n";
        CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return 1;
    }

    dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER) lpFileBase;
    if(dosHeader->e_magic==IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
    {
        std::cout<<"\n DOS Signature (MZ) Matched \n";

        peHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS) ((u_char*)dosHeader+dosHeader->e_lfanew);
        if(peHeader->Signature==IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
        {
            std::cout<<"\n PE Signature (PE) Matched \n";
            //once found valid exe or dll
            std::cout<<"\n Image Base : "<<std::hex<<peHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit hacky but this works too:

[image]
https://ntopcode.wordpress.com/2018/02/26/anatomy-of-the-process-environment-block-peb-windows-internals/

Make sure to include `windows.h`, which ends up including the definition of `NtCurrentTeb` in `winnt.h`, as well as macros and typedefs that `winnt.h` needs, and make sure to include `winternl.h` for `struct _TEB` type definition.

And when I open it up in VMMap:
[image]

(address is different this time because of ASLR)

For .dlls, nobody has mentioned this method yet: http://sandsprite.com/CodeStuff/Understanding_the_Peb_Loader_Data_List.html

Look at the structures in kd and get the right offsets for your system, although it rarely changes across windows versions.

This is only how [`GetModuleHandle`](https://doxygen.reactos.org/de/de3/dll_2win32_2kernel32_2client_2loader_8c.html#aa19e27bdd0da2218ece9f8c3a5b728d2) is implemented anyway. It calls `BasepGetModuleHandleExW` and the functionality is implemented in `RtlPcToFileHeader`. If the parameter is `NULL` then it returns `return ((HMODULE)NtCurrentPeb()->ImageBaseAddress);`, otherwise it will use the `Ldr` member below it in the PEB to parse the list loaded dlls in the address space as shown in the sandsprite link.

[image]

As can be seen, the image base address is also the first module in the initialisation order linked list.

The module handle is just the address cast to a `HMODULE`, which is just a `HINSTANCE` which is a `HANDLE` which is a `PVOID` which is a `void*` 64 bit pointer to a void. Casting as either will have the same effect on the assembly output -- it only aids code level conceptual clarity and compiler warnings, and makes the implementation of the handle transparent to the programmer; they just need to pass the handle to the API functions and not worry about whether it is an index into the handle entries pointed to the handle table pointed to by the `struct _EPROCESS`, a 64-bit raw address or a pseudohandle.

You can view this in `kd` by getting a process ID using Process Explorer and then performing (i.e. if it is pid `16416`, different process to previous example):

```
lkd> ? 0n16416                    //convert denary to hex (output not shown in this example)
lkd> !process 0x4020              //display eprocess for pid (or you can use !process 0n16416 without having to convert to hex) (output not shown in this example)
lkd> .process /P 0xfffffa802edb1a80  //supply eprocess address acquired from the output of the !process command the current; sets current context to the context of that process (output not shown in this example)
lkd> !peb                         //display the PEB of for the current process context                                                                                
PEB at 000007fffffd3000                                                                                                      
    InheritedAddressSpace:    No                                                                                             
    ReadImageFileExecOptions: No                                                                                             
    BeingDebugged:            No                                                                                             
    ImageBaseAddress:         00000000ff0c0000                                                                               
    Ldr                       000000007794d640                                                                               
    Ldr.Initialized:          Yes                                                                                            
    Ldr.InInitializationOrderModuleList: 0000000000343cd0 . 00000000003b3950                                                 
    Ldr.InLoadOrderModuleList:           0000000000343bc0 . 00000000003b3930                                                 
    Ldr.InMemoryOrderModuleList:         0000000000343bd0 . 00000000003b3940                                                 
            Base TimeStamp                     Module                                                                        
        ff0c0000 559ea8be Jul 09 18:00:46 2015 C:\Windows\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE                                               
        77820000 595fa942 Jul 07 16:31:14 2017 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll                                                 
        77700000 595fa987 Jul 07 16:32:23 2017 C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll                                              
     7fefd700000 595fa988 Jul 07 16:32:24 2017 C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll                                            
     7fefed00000 595fa8e2 Jul 07 16:29:38 2017 C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll                                              
     7feffa90000 4eeb033f Dec 16 08:37:19 2011 C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll                                                
     7feff780000 55636728 May 25 19:17:12 2015 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll                                               
     7fefd9a0000 595fa8ec Jul 07 16:29:48 2017 C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll                                                
     7feff100000 5915fd6c May 12 19:22:36 2017 C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll                                                 
        77600000 5824a140 Nov 10 16:33:04 2016 C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll                                                
     7fefee10000 5915fd82 May 12 19:22:58 2017 C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll                                                   
     7fefdad0000 5915fd8f May 12 19:23:11 2017 C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll                                                 
     7fefde20000 4ce7c635 Nov 20 12:59:33 2010 C:\Windows\system32\COMDLG32.dll                                              
     7fefee20000 4ce7c9ab Nov 20 13:14:19 2010 C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll                                               
     7fefcff0000 553a8775 Apr 24 19:12:05 2015 C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0
     7fefdec0000 591331f3 May 10 16:29:55 2017 C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll                                               
     7fefa1d0000 4ce7ca38 Nov 20 13:16:40 2010 C:\Windows\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV                                              
     7fefdba0000 58f4e14a Apr 17 16:37:46 2017 C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll                                                 
     7feff190000 58f4e14e Apr 17 16:37:50 2017 C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll                                              
     7fefd500000 4a5be082 Jul 14 02:33:54 2009 C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll                                               
     7fefede0000 4a5bdf40 Jul 14 02:28:32 2009 C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL                                                 
     7feff980000 57fd0632 Oct 11 16:33:06 2016 C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll                                                 
     7fefd510000 5b046e43 May 22 20:23:47 2018 C:\Windows\system32\nvinitx.dll                                               
        75190000 57f433c5 Oct 04 23:57:09 2016 C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\CoProcManager\detoured.dll                
     7fefa4e0000 5b047092 May 22 20:33:38 2018 C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\CoProcManager\nvd3d9wrapx.dll             
     7feff7a0000 4ce7c9a2 Nov 20 13:14:10 2010 C:\Windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll                                              
     7fefd8e0000 4ce7c55c Nov 20 12:55:56 2010 C:\Windows\system32\CFGMGR32.dll                                              
     7fefd6e0000 4a5bdee1 Jul 14 02:26:57 2009 C:\Windows\system32\DEVOBJ.dll                                                
     7fefa4b0000 5b04708d May 22 20:33:33 2018 C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\CoProcManager\nvdxgiwrapx.dll             
     7fefd2b0000 5a147c83 Nov 21 19:20:35 2017 C:\Windows\system32\guard64.dll                                               
     7fefd290000 5879cba2 Jan 14 06:56:34 2017 C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.DLL                          
     7fefcf80000 4a5bdeff Jul 14 02:27:27 2009 C:\Windows\system32\fltlib.dll                                                
     7fefd430000 595fa9c6 Jul 07 16:33:26 2017 C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll                                             
     7fefb4c0000 4a5be093 Jul 14 02:34:11 2009 C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll                                               
     7fefb090000 559eb4fe Jul 09 18:53:02 2015 C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll                                                
    SubSystemData:     0000000000000000                                                                                      
    ProcessHeap:       0000000000340000                                                                                      
    ProcessParameters: 0000000000342a50                                                                                      
    CurrentDirectory:  'C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\VTune Amplifier XE 2016\'                                        
    WindowTitle:  'C:\Users\lewis\Desktop\support.txt - Shortcut.lnk'                                                        
    ImageFile:    'C:\Windows\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE'        
    DllPath:      'C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\system;C:\Windows;.;C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\VTune Amplifier XE 2016\bin32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Team Tools\Performance Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\Hostx64\x64;C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.10-Q16-HDRI;C:\Users\lewis\Desktop\IDA_Pro_v6.8_and_Hex-Rays_Decompiler_(ARM,x64,x86)\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\bin;C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.10-Q16-HDRI;C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x64)\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\system32\ffmpeg\bin;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\texlive\2017\bin\win32;C:\adb;C:\Users\lewis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\;C:\Users\lewis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts;C:\Users\lewis\Desktop\New folder (2)\sqlmapproject-sqlmap-6402d2e;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\bin;;C:\Users\lewis\AppData\Local\Programs\hyper\resources\bin'
    Environment:  00000000003c7ff0                                                
        =C:=C:\Users\lewis\Desktop
        =ExitCode=00000000
        ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
        APPDATA=C:\Users\lewis\AppData\Roaming
        CLASSPATH=.;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\lib
        CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
        CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
        CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
        COMPUTERNAME=QWERTYUIOP
        ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
        FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
        HOMEDRIVE=C:
        HOMEPATH=\Users\lewis
        JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9
        JDK_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9
        LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\lewis\AppData\Local
        LOGONSERVER=\\QWERTYUIOP
        NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=8
        NVIDIAWHITELISTED=0x01
        ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=undefined
        OS=Windows_NT
        Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\VTune Amplifier XE 2016\bin32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Team Tools\Performance Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\Hostx64\x64;C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.10-Q16-HDRI;C:\Users\lewis\Desktop\IDA_Pro_v6.8_and_Hex-Rays_Decompiler_(ARM,x64,x86)\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\bin;C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.10-Q16-HDRI;C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x64)\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\system32\ffmpeg\bin;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\texlive\2017\bin\win32;C:\adb;C:\Users\lewis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\;C:\Users\lewis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts;C:\Users\lewis\Desktop\New folder (2)\sqlmapproject-sqlmap-6402d2e;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\bin;;C:\Users\lewis\AppData\Local\Programs\hyper\resources\bin
        PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
        PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
        PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
        PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
        PROCESSOR_REVISION=9e09
        ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
        ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
        ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
        ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
        PROMPT=$P$G
        PSModulePath=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
        PT7HOME=C:\Program Files\Cisco Packet Tracer 7.0
        PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
        PYTHON_HOME=C:\Users\lewis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32
        QTJAVA=C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\QTJava.zip
        SESSIONNAME=Console
        SHIM_MCCOMPAT=0x810000001
        SystemDrive=C:
        SystemRoot=C:\Windows
        TEMP=D:\System\Temp
        TMP=D:\System\Temp
        USERDOMAIN=QWERTYUIOP
        USERNAME=lewis
        USERPROFILE=C:\Users\lewis
        VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\
        VTUNE_AMPLIFIER_XE_2016_DIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\VTune Amplifier XE 2016\
        windir=C:\Windows
        windows_tracing_flags=3
        _NT_SYMBOL_PATH=srv*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
        LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
        TERM=xterm-256color
        COLORTERM=truecolor
        TERM_PROGRAM=Hyper
        TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=3.1.0-canary.4
```

To get kernel module bases you can use the `.reload` command followed by `lm`, which will also show the user bases for the current process context that was set by `.process` if the PEB is mapped in when the snapshot is taken (in the case of `livekd`) or at that time (in the case of `kd -kl` local debugging).

`.reload` searches for modules in the PEB in the current process context if the PEB is mapped in in to learn their names, bases and lengths and also traverses `PsLoadedModuleList` to get the kernel module names, bases and lengths, but unloads / does not load symbols for any of the modules except for essential ones, and it loads fewer or more of the essential `.pdb`s depending on whether the `.pdb` is cached locally or whether it needs to download from the symbol server (either to a cache or its own cache in `sym\` if you don't have one specified). You have to load symbols with `ld *` or `.reload /f` and make sure `.sympath` is `srv*C:\localcache\*https://https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`. When the PEB is not mapped in, you'll have to use VMMap / Process Explorer to get the base addresses and lengths of the modules. If the PEB isn't mapped in `.reload kernel32` will not work because it wont be able to find the module, but `.reload kernel32.dll 775c0000,11f000` will work if you tell it where it is by supplying the base and address acquired from Process Explorer. Supplying an address for a module also loads symbols to be used with it starting at that address, regardless of the `/f` setting. `lm` shows all the modules found, the address, address of the first page after the final page allocation, name and whether symbols have been loaded for them in the debugger.