# Why does the address of a function change with every run?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I'm struggling with mapping addresses to their symbols for debugging purposes (getting the callstack). The MS dbghelp.dll can tell the symbol from an address (see `SymFromAddr`, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681323%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). However, it doesn't work and I wonder how this could ever work, because addresses seem to change with every run of the program:

```
#include <iostream>
void Foo() {}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const long unsigned int addr = reinterpret_cast<long unsigned int>(&Foo);
    std::cout << "Address: " << std::hex << addr << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
D:\dev\Sandbox\Debug>Sandbox.exe
Address: 901320
D:\dev\Sandbox\Debug>Sandbox.exe
Address: ce1320
D:\dev\Sandbox\Debug>Sandbox.exe
Address: 3a1320
D:\dev\Sandbox\Debug>Sandbox.exe
Address: 3f1320
```

How could a different program ever read address like from a stacktrace and map it to functions? This sounds like magic to me. I didn't find anything in the linked documentation which says I would have to subtract something from the address or whatever.

In my understanding since we overcome the real-mode every process has a virtual memory space anyway, so no need to roll the dice for a load address any more. I would understand uncertainties of absolute address in case of DLLs, but not the main executable.

Tried on Win7 with VS2008.

Comment: Several answers about this randomization, thanks! I was like WTF!!! How on earth is a stack dump any useful then with this super MS "security through obscurity"?!

Comment: Because all debuggers can deal with modules loaded at random offets. DLLs move all the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Address Space Layout Randomization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384887.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Because your code is compiled to use Address Space Layout Randomization, which makes code less vulnerable to attacks from "StackOverflows".

If you really want to change that, there is a [linker option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384887.aspx) for that.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [security feature that randomises some addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), so a potential attacker can not exploit a known fixed relative position of things.

Answer (score 2):

It's [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) in action, as others have already mentioned.

Looks like what you need to do is to specify the image base for your executable when calling [`SymLoadModuleEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It's the `BaseOfDll` parameter.

I don't know where exactly it's stored in the crash dump (if that's something that that other program has to work with), but a running program can obtain its own image base address using [`GetModuleHandle()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683199%28VS.85%29.aspx) (discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4298331/968261)).

You probably want to save the names and base addresses of all the DLLs loaded into the process as well, not just those of the EXE itself.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I was subtracting the base address in the running code now, so the logfile has relative addresses, and it worked. GetModuleHandle() did the trick. In future I could do with all DLLs, but later.