# Assembly Pointer and base address

Tags: assembly

As i am a assembly language beginner and studying purpose, I am trying scan memory address and pointer in a game. I am kind of confusing about pointer and address.

I found the pointer by a tutorial on youtube, but i want some depth understanding of this pointers and offset.

[image]

[image]
I don't understand how those offset and address add up together and give a final address that stored a value of 1000.

What I understand is that 00F8EBE0 is base address, " 22,20,10,C,20" are five offset.

00F8EBE0 -> 11DA0924 = 1000  How this happen?
How could I read 00F8EBE0 value with C++? Do I need those offset to help me to get the final value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the process's virtual memory space, the image file ("something.exe") is loaded. If you add `0x00F8EBE0` to that address and read that location, you'll get `0x127B5450`. Read the arrows as "points to" and the values in square brackets as "address plus offset". You can programatically get the image base [using the ToolHelp32 API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13346146/87872).

What you have here is a chain of pointers to object structs, with each offset giving you where the next pointer is in the struct/object.

To use this information from another program you can use [ReadProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680553.aspX). Starting from the first offset (the image base), call `ReadProcessMemory` and then add the relevant offset to it, then repeat. The general process is as follows:

```
//assuming you've calculated the image base of the target
//and acquired a handle to the process:

LPVOID base = ImageBase + 0x00F8EBE0; //note: EntryPoint needs obtaining properly
LPVOID value;
ReadProcessMemory(hnd,base,(LPVOID) &value,sizeof value, NULL);
base = value + 0x20;
ReadProcessMemory(hnd,base,(LPVOID) &value,sizeof value, NULL);
base = value + 0xc;
ReadProcessMemory(hnd,base,(LPVOID) &value,sizeof value, NULL);
base = value + 0x10;
ReadProcessMemory(hnd,base,(LPVOID) &value,sizeof value, NULL);
base = value + 0x20;
ReadProcessMemory(hnd,base,(LPVOID) &value,sizeof value, NULL);
base = value + 0x44;
ReadProcessMemory(hnd,base,buf,sizeof value, NULL);
//value will now contain the number 1000.
```

Note that there aren't any guarantees the process' address space will look the same each time it runs; if it allocates any memory the first offset to the entry point (`0x00F8EBE0`) won't be the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you translate a pointer and an offset to C/C++ then you best think in terms of an array. With an array, you have typically a base pointer, which is the array pointer. When you want to access a particular value, you add the index, which translates to the offset.
The simplest case would be a char array, because here you have a 1:1 relation between index and offset.

```
 char p[100];
 p[10] = 32;
```

10 is your offset and assuming that 'p' has a value of 0x1000 then the address where the value 45 is assigned to would be 0x100A.

```
 mov eax, 1000h
 mov [eax+0ah], 20
```

Now the next case would be an integer array where an int has the size of four bytes. Here the index has to be multiplied, which the compiler does for you.

```
 int p[100];
 p[10] = 32;
```

This would translate to:

```
 mov eax, 1000h
 mov edx, 0ah
 mov [eax+edx*4], 20
```

So the target address would be 1000h + 10*4= 40 (28h) -> 1028h

In C++ you have usually classes. From assembler perspective this is the same as a struct, so you have a basepointer, which is the address of your class and the offset addresses each individual member in that particular class/struct. You should keep in mind though, that when you create a strcut/class in C/C++ the compiler can add padding bytes in between the members which essentially means that the offset from a membner is not neccessarily where you would think it is when reading the C/C++ code.

i.E.

```
 struct { char a; int b; } myStruct;
```

The offset of b in this case would most likely be myStruct+2(or 4) and not myStruct+1, because the compiler will likely add an aligment to make it an even address or a DWORD aligned address.