# How to locate the base address of a certain dll in Windows?

Tags: windows, dll

If a process has loaded a certain dll in its address space, how can I determine where the dll 's base address is? I have tried using *depends.exe* but the address it gives is not authentic. The method I am using now is to write a simple WinAPI program, disassemble it and check the address in the *call* instruction. However this method is quite time consuming...

Thanks!

Comment: I think you could use a tool like: http://www.pe-explorer.com/peexplorer-tour-function-view.htm or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/756as972.aspx. If you use `GetModuleHandle()` the return value should be the base address.

Comment: possible duplicate of [EXE or DLL Image base address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298331/exe-or-dll-image-base-address)

Comment: You have been very helpful! Thanks a lot! However, if I move one step further, how can I determine the entry point of a certain function, for example, `MessageBoxA()`? Is there another function similar to `GetModuleHandle()` that can return the entry address of a function?

Comment: To get the address of a function I guess you could do: `void address = (void)MessageBoxA;`. Here is a link that talks about functions pointers: http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/addressfunction.html

Comment: Why don't you use GetProcAddress?

Comment: Thank you! `GetProcAddress` is really an effective way!